# I used cheats to get into the college of winterhold and now it is completely broken

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Well, I talked to the master mage at the front gate and persuaded her.  She asked me to cast magelight and I did and it didn't work.  I used the noclip command to go through the gate and I got into the college.  When I got in I had to listen to the mage.  It gave me a quest to talk to him.  In the middle of it I left.  Now Faralda won't let me in at all and I have no dialogue options to do anything but buy stuff from her or ask about the college.  I need a cheat to start the quest over or complete the first part of the quest.

Comment: I think that you need to start from the last save point and not use cheats this time.

Answer (score 2):

Loading a save from before you did this should fix the problem, assuming you still have one.

If not, you could try using console commands to reset the quest. Enter the following command into the console:

```
ResetQuest MG01
```

This will reset First Lessons- the initial quest of the college of Winterhold. Since your quest progress is now before you've ever spoken to Faralda, you should be able to enter legitimately again.